# update in MVC using aspx file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a series of .aspx (WebForms) files, and I'm transferring them into an ASP.NET MVC environment.

During the Init of my page, I'm calling the following method:

```
displayValues(Model)
```

which is calling this method to populate radio buttons:

```
Sub displayValues(Response As WMPQ.Module.BodyAreaSatisfactionTestResponse)
    With Response
        rblQ7_1.SelectedValue = .Q7_1
        rblQ7_2.SelectedValue = .Q7_2
        rblQ7_3.SelectedValue = .Q7_3
        rblQ7_4.SelectedValue = .Q7_4
        rblQ7_5.SelectedValue = .Q7_5
        rblQ7_6.SelectedValue = .Q7_6
        rblQ7_7.SelectedValue = .Q7_7
        rblQ7_8.SelectedValue = .Q7_8
        txtQ8_1_TEXT.Text = .Q8_1_Text
        .Q8_1 = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(rblQ8_1.SelectedValue), Nothing, Integer.Parse(rblQ8_1.SelectedValue))
        .Q8_2_Text = txtQ8_2_TEXT.Text
        .Q8_2 = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(rblQ8_2.SelectedValue), Nothing, Integer.Parse(rblQ8_2.SelectedValue))
    End With
End Sub
```

I also have an update method, which was previously being called on the buttonclick.  The button click was managing the updating of the datacontext.

```
Sub updateRowValues(Response As WMPQ.Module.BodyAreaSatisfactionTestResponse)
    With Response
        .Q7_1 = rblQ7_1.SelectedValue
        .Q7_2 = rblQ7_2.SelectedValue
        .Q7_3 = rblQ7_3.SelectedValue
        .Q7_4 = rblQ7_4.SelectedValue
        .Q7_5 = rblQ7_5.SelectedValue
        .Q7_6 = rblQ7_6.SelectedValue
        .Q7_7 = rblQ7_7.SelectedValue
        .Q7_8 = rblQ7_8.SelectedValue
        .Q8_1_Text = txtQ8_1_TEXT.Text
        .Q8_1 = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(rblQ8_1.SelectedValue), Nothing, Integer.Parse(rblQ8_1.SelectedValue))
        .Q8_2_Text = txtQ8_2_TEXT.Text
        .Q8_2 = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(rblQ8_2.SelectedValue), Nothing, Integer.Parse(rblQ8_2.SelectedValue))
    End With
End Sub
```

My QUESTION is:  Where or how do I call this code, now that my 'button' is submitting back to the controller?

fyi:

My controller's actions are as follows (this code has clearly not been tested, as I'm still creating the solution):

```
    Function ViewResponse(id As Integer, Page As ResponsesController.EPage)
        Dim db As New WMPQ.Module.ClientResponsesDbContext()

        Dim response = db.ClientResponses.Where(Function(r) r.ClientResponseID = id).First

        If IsNothing(response) Then
            Return RedirectToAction("NewResponse")
        End If

        Select Case Page
            Case ResponsesController.EPage.BodyAreasSatisfactionTest
                Return View("BodyAreasSatisfactionTestDisplay", response.BodyAreaSatisfactionTestResponse)
            Case Else
                RedirectToAction("NewResponse")
        End Select
    End Function

    <HttpPost> _
    Function ViewResponse(model As WMPQ.Module.BodyAreaSatisfactionTestResponse) As ActionResult
        Dim db As New WMPQ.Module.ClientResponsesDbContext()

        If (ModelState.IsValid) Then
            db.Entry(model).State = Entity.EntityState.Modified
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Details", "Responses", New With {.id = model.ClientResponseID})
        End If


        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

At the moment, the httppost function is receiving a completely blank object.  I am calling the updateRowValues method on the codebehind of the submit button, but it's not getting hit.

I would like this to obviously be hit, so that I can update my values.  I also don't want to have to re-develop these aspx pages differently to accommodate, as I have a series of these pages, and they've all been tested and have been working for some time.

Plus, I'm not sure why the object is completely empty. For example, even the original values / keys etc are blanks / zero.

Any help on either matter (not sure if they're related) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right now,  the codebehind of the Ok button (submit) is not being hit, and control goes straight back to the controller, with a completely empty model.

Answer (score 0):

MVC uses the name property of the html attribute to map to the parameters on your action method.  So  in your html form you need to have the radio buttons name attribute match the name of the properties in BodyAreaSatisfactionTestResponse.

Comment: Hi Eric,  thanks for your response.  I've changed my html to include the name property as follows.  The BodyAreaSatisfactionTestResponse is still coming back empty.  I feel that I've pretty close.  I also don't understand why the model, when passed to the aspx is populated, when it comes back it's not.  Here's my html.  thanks: <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblQ7_1" name="Q7_1" runat="server" Width="100%" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="table">